# Unity AI need to move a GameObject towards another one by a given distance

Tags: unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

I'm currently trying to develop an AI for my game that needs to move every minion towards the enemy minions by a specific distance, what I'm currently doing is calculating the distance between all the enemy minions, after that I'll calculate the angle between the current minion and the closest one, and after that I'll apply the formula:

```
x = minion.x + cos(angle) * distance;


z = minion.z + sin(angle) * distance;
```

The problem is that the movement seems random, it doesn't always move towards the enemy but instead, it moves randomly
I'll provide the code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class EnemyAI : MonoBehaviour {

    private float tolerance = 1.2f;

    public NavMeshSurface navMesh;

    private List<GameObject> board;
    private List<Vector3> minionDesiredLocations;

    private int currentMinionIndex = 0;

    private enum State {
        Draw,
        Place,
        GetBoard,
        Move,
        MinionMoving
    }

    private State state = State.Draw;

    public GameObject PlaceCard(List<GameObject> hand)
    {
        //Generate a random integer to see what card to play
        int randomIndex = (int) UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, hand.Count - 1);

        Debug.Log("AI Generated Index: " + randomIndex);

        return hand[randomIndex];
    }

    private bool MoveMinion(GameObject minion, List<GameObject> enemyMinions)
    {
        NavMeshAgent minionAgent = minion.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        Card minionCard = minion.transform.Find("Card").GetComponent<Card>();
        Vector3 maPosition = minion.transform.position;

        //Finding the closest position of the enemy minion
        float minDistance = 100.0f;
        Vector3 closestMinionPosition = Vector3.negativeInfinity; 
        foreach (GameObject enemyMinion in enemyMinions)
        {
            //Calculating distance beetween the enemy AI minion and the enemy
            float distance = Vector3.Distance(minion.transform.position, enemyMinion.transform.position);
            if (distance <= minDistance)
            {
                minDistance = distance;
                //Attacking the minion is close to the one
                if (minDistance <= minionCard.cardRange)
                {
                    float xRange = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-tolerance, tolerance);
                    float yRange = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-tolerance, tolerance);
                    closestMinionPosition = enemyMinion.transform.position + new Vector3(xRange, 0, yRange);

                    minionDesiredLocations[currentMinionIndex] = closestMinionPosition;
                    minionAgent.SetDestination(closestMinionPosition);

                    NavMeshHit hit;
                    if (NavMesh.SamplePosition(closestMinionPosition, out hit, 1.0f, NavMesh.AllAreas))
                    {
                        minionDesiredLocations[currentMinionIndex] = hit.position;
                        minionAgent.SetDestination(hit.position);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Calculating angle beetween the minion and the target
                    float angle = GetAngle(minion.transform.position, enemyMinion.transform.position);

                    float randomDistance = UnityEngine.Random.Range((float)minionCard.cardRange / 2, (float)minionCard.cardRange * 2);
                    randomDistance = 1.0f;

                    float x = minion.transform.position.x + (float)Math.Cos(angle) * randomDistance;
                    float z = minion.transform.position.z + (float)Math.Sin(angle) * randomDistance;

                    closestMinionPosition = new Vector3(x, 0, z);

                    NavMeshHit hit;
                    if (NavMesh.SamplePosition(closestMinionPosition, out hit, 3.0f, NavMesh.AllAreas))
                    {
                        minionDesiredLocations[currentMinionIndex] = hit.position;
                        minionAgent.SetDestination(hit.position);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool PerformTurn(GameController gameController)
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case State.Draw:
                currentMinionIndex = 0;
                gameController.drawCard(1);
                state = State.Place;
                break;
            case State.Place:
                //Getting the hand
                List<GameObject> hand = gameController.GetHand(1);
                //Generate a random integer to see what card to play
                int randomIndex = (int)UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, hand.Count - 1);
                gameController.PlaceMinion(randomIndex);
                state = State.GetBoard;
                break;
            case State.GetBoard:
                board = gameController.GetBoard(1);
                minionDesiredLocations = GenerateActualLocations(board);
                currentMinionIndex = 0;
                state = State.Move;
                break;
            case State.Move:
                //If we have moved all minions
                if (currentMinionIndex >= board.Count)
                {
                    Debug.Log("[IA] Passing turn");
                    state = State.Draw;
                    gameController.NextPlayer();
                    return true;
                }
                else if(MoveMinion(board[currentMinionIndex], gameController.GetBoard(0)))
                {
                    gameController.SetCameraTo(board[currentMinionIndex].transform.position);
                    MoveMinion(board[currentMinionIndex], gameController.GetBoard(0));
                    state = State.MinionMoving;
                }
                break;
            case State.MinionMoving:
                Vector3 actualMinionPosition = board[currentMinionIndex].transform.position;
                Vector3 desiredMinionLocation = minionDesiredLocations[currentMinionIndex];
                actualMinionPosition = new Vector3(actualMinionPosition.x, 0, actualMinionPosition.z);
                desiredMinionLocation = new Vector3(desiredMinionLocation.x, 0, desiredMinionLocation.z);
                if (actualMinionPosition == desiredMinionLocation)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Next Minion");
                    currentMinionIndex++;
                    state = State.Move;
                }
                //Debug lines
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.P))
                {
                    Debug.Log("Next Minion");
                    currentMinionIndex++;
                    state = State.Move;
                }
                break;
        }

        //Continue turn proccessing
        return false;
    }

    private List<Vector3> GenerateActualLocations(List<GameObject> board)
    {
        List<Vector3> l = new List<Vector3>();
        foreach (GameObject minion in board)
        {
            l.Add(minion.transform.position);
        }
        return l;
    }

    private float GetAngle(Vector3 minion, Vector3 target)
    {
        return Vector3.Angle(minion, target);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you confirm that the value of closestMinionPosition is correct?

Comment: And what happen if NavMesh.SamplePosition return false?

Comment: Have you tried using a hard coded distance, that doesnt depend on random to make sure the movement is indeed correct?  also please provide a  minimum complete verifiable example of how to reproduce your issue, right now all we can do is take a stab in the dark of what is going on.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes the value of closestMinionPosition is always correct, and if NavMesh.SamplePosition return false the IA will recall the method to calculate a new position

Comment: I'll try hard coded distances right now, and i'll provide the full source of the method

Comment: I suggest you use something like debug.drawline to debug. And use a simple scene to test.

Comment: The scene that i use to test is quite simple, a really simple navmesh surface and a limited set of gameobjects, by hard coding the direction vector it works like a charm, but the minions keep going in that direction so at a certain point they will get stuck, by using Debug.DrawLine() i've managed to draw a line between the minion and the closest enemy one, and it works all the time, maybe i'm doing some math wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I've finally found a solution.
What I've done was calling

```
agent.SetDestination(enemyMinion.transform.position)
```

After that I've stored the starting position of the agent, and inside of the logic loop, check the distance between the starting position and the actual position, whenever the distance is greater than the distance that the minion can walk, I'll simply stop the NavMeshAgent

Here's the updated code in case someone needs it

```
using System;
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class EnemyAI : MonoBehaviour {

private float tolerance = 1.2f;

public NavMeshSurface navMesh;

private List<GameObject> board;
private List<Vector3> minionDesiredLocations;
private Vector3 startMinionLocation;

private int currentMinionIndex = 0;

private enum State {
    Draw,
    Place,
    GetBoard,
    Move,
    MinionMoving
}

private State state = State.Draw;

public GameObject PlaceCard(List<GameObject> hand)
{
    //Generate a random integer to see what card to play
    int randomIndex = (int) UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, hand.Count - 1);

    Debug.Log("AI Generated Index: " + randomIndex);

    return hand[randomIndex];
}

private bool MoveMinion(GameObject minion, List<GameObject> enemyMinions)
{
    NavMeshAgent minionAgent = minion.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    Card minionCard = minion.transform.Find("Card").GetComponent<Card>();
    Vector3 maPosition = minion.transform.position;

    //Finding the closest position of the enemy minion
    float minDistance = 100.0f;
    Vector3 closestMinionPosition = Vector3.negativeInfinity; 
    foreach (GameObject enemyMinion in enemyMinions)
    {
        //Calculating distance beetween the enemy AI minion and the enemy
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(minion.transform.position, enemyMinion.transform.position);
        if (distance <= minDistance)
        {
            minDistance = distance;
            //Attacking the minion is close to the one
            float xRange = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-tolerance, tolerance);
            float yRange = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-tolerance, tolerance);
            closestMinionPosition = enemyMinion.transform.position + new Vector3(xRange, 0, yRange);

            minionDesiredLocations[currentMinionIndex] = closestMinionPosition;
            minionAgent.SetDestination(closestMinionPosition);

            NavMeshHit hit;
            if (NavMesh.SamplePosition(closestMinionPosition, out hit, 1.0f, NavMesh.AllAreas))
            {
                minionDesiredLocations[currentMinionIndex] = hit.position;
                minionAgent.isStopped = false;
                minionAgent.SetDestination(hit.position);
                startMinionLocation = minion.transform.position;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public bool PerformTurn(GameController gameController)
{
    switch (state)
    {
        case State.Draw:
            currentMinionIndex = 0;
            gameController.drawCard(1);
            state = State.Place;
            break;
        case State.Place:
            //Getting the hand
            List<GameObject> hand = gameController.GetHand(1);
            //Generate a random integer to see what card to play
            int randomIndex = (int)UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, hand.Count - 1);
            gameController.PlaceMinion(randomIndex);
            state = State.GetBoard;
            break;
        case State.GetBoard:
            board = gameController.GetBoard(1);
            minionDesiredLocations = GenerateActualLocations(board);
            currentMinionIndex = 0;
            state = State.Move;
            break;
        case State.Move:
            //If we have moved all minions
            if (currentMinionIndex >= board.Count)
            {
                Debug.Log("[IA] Passing turn");
                state = State.Draw;
                gameController.NextPlayer();
                return true;
            }
            else if(MoveMinion(board[currentMinionIndex], gameController.GetBoard(0)))
            {
                gameController.SetCameraTo(board[currentMinionIndex].transform.position);
                MoveMinion(board[currentMinionIndex], gameController.GetBoard(0));
                state = State.MinionMoving;
            }
            break;
        case State.MinionMoving:
            Vector3 actualMinionPosition = board[currentMinionIndex].transform.position;

            float distance = Vector3.Distance(startMinionLocation, actualMinionPosition);
            Card card = board[currentMinionIndex].transform.Find("Card").GetComponent<Card>();
            NavMeshAgent agent = board[currentMinionIndex].GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();

            if (distance >= card.cardRange)
            {
                agent.isStopped = true;
                currentMinionIndex++;
                state = State.Move;
            }
            //Debug lines
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.P))
            {
                Debug.Log("Next Minion");
                currentMinionIndex++;
                state = State.Move;
            }
            break;
    }

    //Continue turn proccessing
    return false;
}

private List<Vector3> GenerateActualLocations(List<GameObject> board)
{
    List<Vector3> l = new List<Vector3>();
    foreach (GameObject minion in board)
    {
        l.Add(minion.transform.position);
    }
    return l;
}

private float GetAngle(Vector3 minion, Vector3 target)
{
    return Vector3.Angle(minion, target);
}
}
```